# Compressing response in Spring Boot controller and inflating in JavaScript

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, compression, deflate

We’ve tried using a Deflater Output Stream and a GZIP Output Stream on the server side to compress the response, and the Pako module on the client side to decompress it. Using deflater gives the console error “uncaught exception: invalid distance too far back” in the browser, and using gzip gives “uncaught exception: invalid block type”.

From what I’ve read, the browser should be able to uncompress the response itself, but using “response.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");” doesn’t work. There’s no error, the response just doesn’t have that header when the browser receives it.

The deflater code:

```
    private static String compress(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try
            {
                final DeflaterOutputStream def = new DeflaterOutputStream(out, new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true));
                try
                {
                    def.write(str.getBytes());                    
                    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(out.toByteArray()));
                }
                finally
                {def.close();}
            }
            finally
            {out.close();}
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            LOGGER.warn("Failed to compress.");
        }
  return str;
```

The Gzip code.

```
    try
    {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try
        {    
            final GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
            try
            {gzip.write(str.getBytes());}
            finally
            {gzip.close();}

            return out.toString("UTF-8");
        }
        finally
        {out.close();}
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {LOGGER.warn("Failed to compress.");}

    return str;
}
```

The pako call

```
LandAdditions.prototype.loadfields = function() {
    let me = this;

    me.loadingBanner().show();

    var url =
    "/rest/accounts/" + app.accountIdBox().val() + "/land_additions/fields";

  $.get(url)
    .done(function(data) {
      me.onLoadFields(JSON.parse(pako.inflateRaw(data, { to: 'string'})));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Deflater (sic) is producing raw deflate data, which you are then Base-64 encoding. Your pako decoder is not first decoding the Base-64 encoding, so inflateRaw is getting a bunch of Base-64 characters instead of the raw deflate stream it is expecting.

The GZIPOutputStream is producing a gzip-wrapped deflate stream. inflateRaw is expecting a raw deflate stream, but is instead getting a gzip header, which it is not looking for and interprets as invalid deflate data.

For the first one you need to decode Base-64. For the second, you need to decode gzip data, for which pako has ungzip.

By the way, you don't want to encode binary data as UTF-8. UTF-8 cannot represent all binary sequences.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We've gone back to GZIPOutputStream on the server side, but when we use pako.ungzip we get the error: 'incorrect header check'.